# Blade template yield with default include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is it possible to yield to another view but then default with an include statement?

Example:

```
@yield('header', @include('partials.header'))
```

The intended action is that if the subview does not include the header, then the current template will include the partials.header view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible. But you can't use blade tags inside blade tags. What you can do however is use `View::make()` instead of `@include`. `@include` actually compiles to a `make` call on the view factory.

```
@yield('header', View::make('partials.header'))
```

Comment: This is a sweet tip Mr. Geiter!

Comment: +1 for working solution. I just hate the inconsistency and would really like a blade solution. I am sure it will be implemented later if not already.